# Hyperlink to local report

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to link Reports in an application without a server?

If i click a link in Report A it opens report B with some parameters.

Both reports are only availble locally.

More concrete i would like to reload (link) the same Report with other parameters.

Comment: With help of *Java* you can do everything you want :)

Comment: [Hyperlinks](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/hyperlink/index.html#hyperlinks)